# Sourcetree push to bitbucket using LFS not wanting to work (Error [17])

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, bitbucket, sourcetree

After a year or so of Unity development without using a decent VCS/cloud storage backup I've finally decided it is time to move to bitbucket.  Sourcetree seemed like the logical path and I got it installed, logged into my bitbucket account, etc., all without issue.  After setting up my first repository on my side and trying to make the initial commit and push, I'm getting the following errors

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c lfs.customtransfer.bitbucket-media-api.path=git-lfs-bitbucket-media-api push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master
Pushing to <MYBITBUCKETADDRESS>

Git LFS: (0 of 43 files, 2 skipped) 0 B / 18.07 MB, 48.18 KB skipped           
Git LFS: (0 of 43 files, 2 skipped) 0 B / 18.07 MB, 48.18 KB skipped           

Error transferring "91b2a528945bad64bdf71b2a83874c1d062ba9350d90aee5a21bd6319bb72a4f": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/8671c49b-ceb3-4e7e-b37e-5ab85d627b43/chunks
Error transferring "7476d2304d22dccf4717064f1ec656124fc86c531cefb61f4cde671aeb0da3ba": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/98ac7cd0-23b8-4749-b2ea-fe4eed4ef6ed/chunks
Error transferring "9e8a4f96b534f8489a2230e97f76e9ff702b7479c2bd29fa514eef17c3fd8a4a": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/0a34b0d6-1eaa-4401-a5c3-716f65c0f7c2/chunks
Error transferring "f4628b3fe433c6b7210e44c4bac1f0890f22cd2535d2d5680c7df24466a8c2da": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/183f6a94-a741-4b43-95c9-d7a4879f5d04/chunks
Error transferring "388f6877e904b325af0a39ca8c2a5b1677cf0a033a856d5ad96ef65f7eea7320": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/52729e71-57f3-4e03-b55d-4b23625a88f1/chunks
Error transferring "74e45baa87c5c316211cc3b906ac1cd54518adcb41cde64f119e0c05eece3fec": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/30c2258d-fb18-468c-8252-ef8d6bb79c44/chunks
Error transferring "b3ddb2c38040b3233c172769982275d8715b4fa282dd18c05d1ac5221036b41c": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/ac6eb838-e7b8-4c84-a059-bcbcbef2bf66/chunks
Error transferring "5a1188d43def78b00ed7d3560d1b03ea52f7fcbc6f6edbd6d36f96fbf3fff359": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/95c66b58-ab67-4f96-bf09-f6a173240473/chunks
Error transferring "2f42b66be84c34b062eb50204a69bce15e4d2f4e1d9a4839844c3ce0dae32390": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/c0e5c819-d575-4f24-a880-ffdbc9dbd00c/chunks
Error transferring "43d3016b39bf9d2c00a65900cecd7b3c550c3145fcd67145c02e83c0880ce0eb": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/3b22dc8d-8b11-462b-b93e-762231b8bec1/chunks
Error transferring "79dc6195262f3c50132bf42dbf3e1786051e62b7855016ade05e68ccddbfe428": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/18de823c-0e11-4873-87f0-8011f4e94af5/chunks
Error transferring "f22b8ec9ab4c79c878e8affcb9d4dd269848f9e94ce03b0b1d92a408d4a498c4": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/157354fc-e3c2-4708-9130-246078783795/chunks
Error transferring "15902aab1b6f98501f4d285eeb94f9577a4ccf7e32e4c3eba74679520c5f12c8": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/e2008de5-9497-4ede-8c1c-5d88f2a5d3a3/chunks
Error transferring "d78fdd756451e87aa8bf989010989c52311178927f298cf069c9de145f2fd7e9": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/1fe50fb5-d53c-4aea-a5f2-9ff5bac3d1a4/chunks
Error transferring "700b2bfb9897e4ccc9e8a3e9334b359d9b3256bdb0310e6e140b9068dec93c6f": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/2ff8b578-aa0b-47cc-af31-a455ba9c5600/chunks
Error transferring "c9baa5d8edcbf5cff9f513555113f689cf48c7704fe75c2fffad81922188c9a1": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/d403b9b2-8ba8-431d-a6f3-c46335efed6d/chunks
Error transferring "0f51136a1eab11cd05ad0fbdc3753601c2fe724c2a137bdb664bf18626272bad": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/e809957e-9fc7-4567-9435-f642f9153bbf/chunks
Error transferring "dbbc1c3186c72b07689f310be623b992b2bebc9974d0a69109d2f3ee8a52cfc6": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/2c25c83a-446c-4d96-9828-1b8c51e071d4/chunks
Error transferring "9384e2a9299337d27b98650e8c01506d7f4225432ea8178e3aba657a46043b47": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/95af6872-8597-4cfd-93ea-d1bd999f7311/chunks
Error transferring "2d0e45a24d63620270d0d813662366f3ca052833fa7577f8e55d54e52815d1c0": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/f684c413-70c4-4795-bfd8-bcfdc29437d7/chunks
Error transferring "6bf4b7343f25cf5c042034240864c821ce3c4f523f6d362a745c269d423697a1": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/a47b286b-98d8-4d7a-a06d-e17545f6511d/chunks
Error transferring "f5237f9288dcf987a47ac772025c72b147a97db81da81e8a4477b8c71d1e4fc8": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/5c3f1cd7-20b2-4ee8-8621-cb4bf19f8a99/chunks
Error transferring "f4d92bdac378480d82f96304d0daa5d754c9ed1cc76e047c79a06f92849c9c7a": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/ae639f7e-3218-43ab-8b15-e5b85d03e4e0/chunks
Error transferring "1d2be9f2c1c0f1dd252b003b8118b9ae53a3adfcd83b728e9c839b3c3b343502": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/110fc888-e9c1-410b-92cc-a51e2de6b74c/chunks
Error transferring "b6a0424a4b88ce1cd7acf93c1b8dbc43c045d0d7d86ea75b790c7265d1c8bf97": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/6e1acfb9-84fd-461c-9e93-b4d5e1f16f49/chunks
Error transferring "d9ccfbc0a0424be4f17efa9014e369c95a0b82f9fedcaf512ad2ee25fc7eccfd": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/8cc7316f-909b-40ce-833a-cb201556cb28/chunks
Error transferring "bb05a1447699d649fa1437b2b36927afbf7e9d400bb713008e1ec4ebf9988667": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/7eb560b5-f296-43dc-9738-129731b10a87/chunks
Error transferring "2bda1a241f3737d7f1a74be28ff717043cf16c2486c797d5161a590952cb06ee": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/0422cabc-1431-4b17-9b56-505958eba33f/chunks
Error transferring "aebfb6f558ee6132706bddf1089f1701edcef65db868f3869448b9597744dca8": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/b78035fd-fd42-40a9-8db0-67209f24d9b1/chunks
Error transferring "13ff1b1ea86a38afe9209b8e33c0eec91d03000bad5eea9da56e2688617cf000": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/ddb533c4-8c0b-4550-9442-52a6410f25ac/chunks
Error transferring "c2bb076f72e4f8a0a0adf48a26b25f4c8360555bf7eb9b0c33b78f91f034cbbe": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/2bbd2279-a60d-4241-91af-a10f74b49cb2/chunks
Error transferring "f2d8200be81b09c1c419deb5f791c41516bb52b827d2f34e4a5863d059e77768": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/d7d52190-7df1-495b-9576-1d2f01f03a07/chunks
Error transferring "819bbc6bf4cc2f756b8a8efaac12a0b1ab27940eb073b7276f246328a8b6300c": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/82caccdb-b990-4f85-92be-a012e384b42c/chunks
Error transferring "c7e2d89bdb0fb2ea7b9a9ac6f0c50eacf707589434fc5c7d78eaab026d21b0d1": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/1546893c-6f23-4551-b85c-5967c82d58c7/chunks
Error transferring "1d82846b6b683c7a23468444eb14702bc356c9a5852c46fcb35eb0996e6b9b0b": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/a7cb793e-d8ab-4649-9658-0f3d91f8f123/chunks
Error transferring "4fa395cb54467a86347359345d1e75ab64d7324dfa81e841e804278a608ce21c": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/996cdea5-d889-4a59-93b4-e63296614183/chunks
Error transferring "0e4ea91b0650b04f5e93e6419ceb4b51ed6ce1f2dcc2c5e73f4859a01e9a63b7": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/93436107-027b-44ea-81c8-6bf2edeab2ed/chunks
Error transferring "a7d2b91d8ba1cdb527d5e856339d1cd85fd3c5b900816c3ee713a45e7b9b1eed": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/e8fd4aca-d854-41d4-8354-50da1023c8fe/chunks
Error transferring "e7a458a830fccee035631edf448d70e60cd5f05bb73c2f11d973eb9bbd541449": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/3f883e4d-eca3-4a01-9815-c8a171d9e81f/chunks
Error transferring "c1f64575e1ef6267f54651cabcf0ad26d030817ae42fb0d94e00b77c80bdf39e": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/dd788f68-af04-4216-b4b5-59fab0280a05/chunks
Error transferring "78a788bf8b1992d55b37a6ba6ae4229f82e425392c9a6a7ba967672b403f3388": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/5771aca7-e25c-4afa-9ddc-07f7254d6d33/chunks
Error transferring "452f65e43ed6262ddfc65216cea69fb00f9021f4f9dea606d0003f7630b9cf1d": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/46062152-a9df-4bea-b384-baec2cc92480/chunks
Error transferring "0aefaa9d17684ede4503547a193ded4e4ef72812b8c7b81594fbaa0b6e14363f": [17] Error sending chunk details to media api: StatusCode 400 Bad Request from /upload/b4625081-3f1c-45e4-98d9-482741bd5c08/chunks

error: failed to push some refs to '<MYBITBUCKETADDRESS'
Completed with errors, see above.
```

I've done some searching but have yet to find a solution other than reinstall Sourcetree and hope for the best (didn't work) so I'm hoping SO can help me figure it out.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem pushing changes with lfs files. It seems to be a bug in the most recent version of SourceTree (1.9.9.20). Try installing the previous version from [here](http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.9.6.2.exe). It solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem.
The solution is using command line.

1. Change url to use git instead https in config.
2. Install git-lfs and Bitbucket LFS Media Adapter [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-lfs-media-adapter-856699998.html).
3. $ git push

```html
$ git push
Git LFS: (18 of 18 files, 38 skipped) 90.76 MB / 90.76 MB, 234.19 MB skipped
Counting objects: 12731, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5997/5997), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12731/12731), 102.82 MiB | 3.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 12731 (delta 6807), reused 11383 (delta 6640)
To bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Hope this will help.